# Navigation bar not displayed when view controller is presented as a popover on iPad (versus push on iPhone when it is displayed)

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uipopovercontroller

I am converting an iPhone App to an iPad App. I wish to present several of the view controllers as popovers that were previously pushed on the iPhone by changing the segue type in the storyboard from push to popover. The view controllers have a title, a done button, and a cancel button in the navigation bar. Now, when I run the iPad App the popover appears but without the navigation bar. How can I get the navigation bar to show. I have already tried expected setting it not hidden in viewWillAppear which did not work.

I have been able to change the segue to an IBAction with the following code and got it to work. It seems somehow the popover does not have a navigation controller so I created one. `

```
    // Device is iPad
        addNoteVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addNoteVC"];
        popoverNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addNoteVC];
        [addNoteVC setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [popoverNav.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor darkTextColor]];
        NSDictionary *textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [UIColor darkTextColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil];
        [popoverNav.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes];
        [addNoteVC setSelectedClient:selectedClient];
        [addNoteVC setAddNoteTableViewControllerDelegate:self];
        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController: popoverNav];
        [popover setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];
        popover.delegate = self;
        [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
`
```

While the above code works it creates significant differences from the iPhone App code. I would rather that the iPhone and iPad stayed the same as much as possible. If adding a another navigation controller for the popover is the only solution I would prefer to do this in a custom segue so the view controller code can stay the same. In addition that approach would have the economy of one custom segue instead of changes for every view controller presented as a popover. If that indeed is the best solution, details on the custom segue would be appreciated and accepted.

Comment: I'm a little confused on why you would want/need a UINavigationController as part of the popover.  That doesn't make a lot of sense.  You don't really need Cancel or Done in a popover.  Cancel can just be the user tapping away from the popover and Done can be triggered whenever the user makes a selection.  That's what the HIG guidelines would recommend anyway.

Comment: @ChrisAllwein, the view controllers were designed for the iPhone and I would like to reuse them as is with the iPad. While one can cancel on the iPad by tapping away, that doesn't remove my purpose for the navigation bar because that is where the title and done button are displayed.